# Do you know how to do this animation using Core Animation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, animation, core-animation

I am using core animation to create a 3d cube and make it rotate, but it is only rotating in one direction. My project is using UIKit but the animation has to be something like this one (that is made in Swift UI): https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-animations-3d-rotation-effect-fb8dd5b86df

I am new with Core Animation and I would be really grateful you could help me.

The code for the animation that I am doing is the following one:

```
   let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    anim.fromValue = cube.transform
    anim.toValue = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 1, 1, 1)
    anim.duration = 0.5
    anim.isCumulative = true
    anim.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    cube.add(anim, forKey: "transform")
```

Where cube is a CATransformLayer

Comment: What does "in one direction" mean? You are only supplying one transform animation and so it only _has_ one direction (though I'm not entirely clear on what a "direction" is when we're talking about a 3d rotation).